Azure Databricks Statement Execution API: how to overcome "Azure storage request is not authorized" error
I'm attempting to query Azure Databricks delta lake via the Statement Execution API from a C# .NET application. Here is the application code:
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DatabricksApiApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Set up the endpoint and the access token
                string baseUrl = "https://adb-7765225718529619.19.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/sql/statements";
                string accessToken = "dapbmi7a544bbc6d0e05a1ec650b85570b70";
                string warehouseId = "ff9d6456ff77bcs84";

                // Prepare the HTTP request
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, baseUrl)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(
                        "{\"statement\":\"SELECT * FROM maindev.default.product_1\", \"warehouse_id\":\"ff9d6456ff77bcs84\", \"timeout_seconds\":600}",
                        Encoding.UTF8,
                        "application/json"
                    )
                };
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

                // Send the request
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                // Check the response
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Data retrieved successfully!");
                    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve data. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Response Body: {responseBody}");
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

The request reaches Databricks fine. As I understand it, in order to return the data to my application, this request needs to make use of some Azure storage. This is where I receive this error:
This Azure storage request is not authorized. The storage account's 'Firewalls and virtual networks' settings may be blocking access to storage services. Please verify your Azure storage credentials or firewall exception settings.

As you can tell, the error does not specify what specific storage needs to be authorized.
What can I do to overcome this error?

This issue had to do with using a serves sql warehouse. Our security would not allow that external entity to access our internal storage. Once we switched over to a dedicated sql warehouse - no issues.
